# How can I change only the text margins to be inside the equation and section numbers?

Tags: align, margins, paragraphs

How can I change only the text margins to be inside the equation and section numbers?

Something Like this[image]

Comment: [Welcome to LaTeX! Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to go, using the `titlesec` and `etoolbox` packages:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}% just to generate text for the example
\usepackage[pagestyles]{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}{\normalsize\bfseries\MakeUppercase}%
{\llap{\arabic{section}\hskip1cm}}{0pt}{}
\usepackage{mathtools, etoolbox}
\BeforeBeginEnvironment{equation}{\rightskip=1.25cm}

\begin{document}

\section{Sets}

\begin{equation}
  x +y = a + b
\end{equation}

\section{Mappings}
\lipsum[1]
```

[image]
    \end{document}